# more efficient alternative to representation of time extended flow network with adjacency tensor

Tags: algorithm

So, I want to solve max flow over time problem, by extending the original graph (in a form of adjacency matrix) to adjacency tensor and running ford-Fulkerson algorithm, where instead of two dimensions (representing from and to vertices) there also would be dispatched at and received at dimensions. This however seem to be very hard on memory space used. I think I might be overlooking something, so I'm asking for an advice on more efficient way.